# Using socket.io rooms in treeline using sockets machine pack

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, treeline

I am using sockets machine pack in treeline to subscribe and broadcast messages to particular rooms.

But, i am struggling to get it running by subscribing to a room and sending messages to a particular room. As, when using 'join room' machine. it asks for unique socket ids and whenever i try to get the socket ids from 'getRequestingSocketId' it throws a 500 error. Any help would be deeply appericiated!

I created two routes:
POST /subscribe
POST /senddata

To subscribe to a room
I pass a parameter {roomid: 'room'} with the url /subscribe to subscribe the user to the 'room' room. It asks for a unique socket id here, but when i use 'getRequestingSocketId' it throws the 500 error, when calling the api.

and /senddata is used to send data to that particular room later, here: 'room' room

P.S. I used a common event name to try to send the data

Can you please help me with how to setup socket subscriptions to send data using treeline please ?

Thank you!